# Eclipse crashes when running dynamic web app

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, java

I am trying to run a dynamic web application in eclipse 3.7 (indigo) using Apache Tomcat v7.0.
The project is empty when i try to run (Run > Run on server) eclipse crashes.

I am running on Ubuntu 13.04.

Also when i run eclipse from command line. I get error as -

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9a0c4c2009, pid=7501, tid=140300945577728
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b02
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6e009]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x19
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try                 "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/swapnilg/hs_err_pid7501.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

[Log File Content](http://pastebin.com/2FTwXCqR)

Please help me. I have even tried changing the JDK, Tomcat and eclipse version.

Comment: please post the error log:`/home/swapnilg/hs_err_pid7501.log`

Comment: Its a pretty big file..

Comment: this log is necessary for a better understanding of the error, post only the lines relative to this error

Comment: Does the Tomcat log have an errors in it?

Comment: the file is of 135kb and only 30000 characters is allowed.

Comment: i dont think so. since i have tried tomcat 6 and 7 both.

Comment: @fmodos: Updated. Please help me now.

Comment: @fmodos: help please..

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me when i changed the browser to access to run the web app.

OS:UBUNTU 14.04 
Eclipse: Eclipse kepler
Server: Apache tomcat 7

Did this - `Window-->Web browser-->Default Web Browser.`

Answer (score 3):

It crashes because eclipse is trying to open the internal browser to show the webapp. I don't know why this error is happening, maybe an eclipse bug with ubuntu.

One work around is to run the server using the `Servers View` instead the `Run As`. Go to `Servers View->Right Click the Server->Run`

Comment: Its a bug in eclipse, you can avoid opening the browser inside eclipse by adding this in eclipse.ini: `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

Answer (score 2):

i also faced the same error once while starting TOMCAT but after increasing the heap size of Java from eclipse it started working .

Comment: i have increased eclipse heap size
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same problem and tried multiple solutions. I got work-around for it when I added 
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla in eclipse.ini file.